# Trying to send a nested JSON through a HTTP 'POST' request in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, http, npm

I'm trying to send an array of json objects to a local server by an HTTP 'POST' request. I've been using an npm module found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request to do the request. I've done this before and for the most part my code works fine, but I have an issue I've been unable to resolve.

```
var request = require('request');
const obj = require('./bugs.json');

obj.forEach(element => {
    // Set the headers
  var headers = {
    'Content-Type': "stuff",
    'x-authorization': "stuff"
  }

  // Configure the request
  var options = {
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/bugreport/import',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: headers,
      form: {
          'subject': element.subject,
          'description': element.description,
          'platform': element.platform,
          'date': element.date,
          'author': element.author,
          'isSolved': element.isSolved,
          'createdAt': element.createdAt,
          'updatedAt': element.updatedAt,
          'id': element.id
      }  
  }
//
  // Start the request
  request(options, function(error, response, body){
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
          console.log("No error detected.");
          console.log(body)
      }
      else {
          console.log("Error: " + error);
      }
  })

});
```

The problematic line is `'author': element.author,`  While every other attribute is a basic data type, author is itself a nested json. Here is what the json file looks like:

```
[
    {
    "subject": "Bug",
    "description": "Testing brscript",
    "platform": "A",
    "date": "2/15/2018",
    "author": [
        {
            "username": "testuser1",
            "firstName": "test",
            "lastName": "user1",
            "password": "password",
            "admin": false,
            "isVisible": true,
            "isDeleted": false,
            "createdAt": "2018-02-08T18:42:58.473Z",
            "updatedAt": "2018-02-13T15:51:17.954Z",
            "id": 170
        }
    ],
    "isSolved": false,
    "createdAt": "2/15/2018",
    "updatedAt": "2/15/2018",
    "id": 999
    }
]
```

As I said, I've done this before, but not with a nested json as one of my attributes. Everything but the author json will send. So, there must be something wrong with my syntax. I've tried several different approaches to get it to recognize the json, but none have worked.

Comment: please post the error message

Comment: The error is that author is a required attribute and the server doesn't recognize it. "1 attribute is invalid."

Comment: Instead of `form: { a bunch of stuff }`, try `form: element`

Answer (score 0):

try using `JSON.stringify(body)` in your `console.log()`

also `application/json` in your header `Content-Type`